# How to provide input to an active bash script running via cron

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script that runs many times daily.  The amount of times run vary depending on how long the script takes to run.  At one point in the script, I would like to be able to provide input.  Basically, I would like the script to provide output in the log file it is writing asking for input.  I'm thinking the best way is to have the script go into an "infinte" while loop and every 5 minutes check if a file is present.  I know how to check if a file is present but I'm still fairly new to bash scripting so I'm not sure how to write the code to get into the while loop.  I appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the question that you asked is:

```
# Wait for file to be created
while [ ! -f "input_file" ]
do
    sleep 5m
done
# Do something now that the file exists
```

It might, though, be better practice to have the cronjob run every 5 minutes and exit if the file doesn't yet exist.

Comment: This will work perfectly.  I will add the following above the sleep line: echo "`date +20%y%m%d-%H:%M:%S`: Input Required, write file zzz"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [`zenity` package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) installed, you can use this to create custom gui dialog boxes.  In my testing, this seems to work OK when used from a script started by `cron`.  For example we have this little example script, which I have called "proceed.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
if zenity --display=:0 --question; then
    zenity --display=:0 --info  --text="You pressed yes"
else
    zenity --display=:0 --info  --text="You pressed no"
fi
```

and add a cron entry (this runs every minute - you probably don't want that):

```
* * * * * ~/proceed.sh
```

Note we need to hard-code which display the dialog boxes go to, as scripts in the cron context wouldn't otherwise know.

There are a whole bunch of options for zenity to allow you to create custom dialog boxes.